# Console.WriteLine does not show up in Output window

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have put some `Console.WriteLine` calls in to test, but they aren't appearing in the output box?

```
public static ArrayList myDeliveries = new ArrayList();

public mainForm(){
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void mainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){

    if (!File.Exists("../../MealDeliveries.txt")){
        MessageBox.Show("File not found!");
        return;
    }

    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("../../MealDeliveries.txt")){
        //first line is delivery name 
        string strDeliveryName = sr.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Test content");

        while (strDeliveryName != null){

            //other lines 
            Delivery d = new Delivery(
                strDeliveryName, 
                sr.ReadLine(),
                sr.ReadLine(), 
                sr.ReadLine(),
                sr.ReadLine(), 
                sr.ReadLine(),
                sr.ReadLine()
            );

            mainForm.myDeliveries.Add(d);

            //check for further values
            strDeliveryName = sr.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    displayDeliveries();


}


private void displayDeliveries(){

    lstDeliveryDetails.Items.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine("Test content");
    Console.WriteLine(mainForm.myDeliveries.Count);
    foreach (Delivery d in mainForm.myDeliveries){
        lstDeliveryDetails.Items.Add(d.DeliveryName);

    }
}
```

Can anyone help??

Answer (score 68, accepted):

If you intend to use this output in production, then use the [Trace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.aspx) class members.  This makes the code portable, you can wire up different types of listeners and output to the console window, debug window, log file, or whatever else you like.

If this is just some temporary debugging code that you're using to verify that certain code is being executed or has the correct values, then use the [Debug](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.aspx) class as [Zach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669463/console-writeline-does-not-show-up-in-output-window/2669496#2669496) suggests.

If you absolutely must use the console, then you can [attach a console](http://www.codeproject.com/tips/68979/Attaching-a-Console-to-a-WinForms-application.aspx) in the program's `Main` method.

Answer (score 180):

`Console` outputs to the console window and Winforms applications do not show the console window.  You should be able to use `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine` to send output to the output window in your IDE.

**Edit:** In regards to the problem, have you verified your `mainForm_Load` is actually being called?  You could place a breakpoint at the beginning of `mainForm_Load` to see.  If it is not being called, I suspect that `mainForm_Load` is not hooked up to the `Load` event.

Also, it is more efficient and generally better to override `On{EventName}` instead of subscribing to `{EventName}` from within derived classes (in your case overriding `OnLoad` instead of `Load`).

Comment: Like this?
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("some tetttttttttt23423423423423423ttttttttttttttttttttttt");

Comment: @Luke - yes, but you can `Import System.Diagnostics` to make it much simpler.  And I prefer using the `Trace` class for this.

Comment: In the top navbar of Visual Studio go to View > Output to see the values from `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine`.

Answer (score 19):

If you want `Console.WriteLine("example text")` output to show up in the Debug Output window, temporarily change the Output type of your Application from Console Application to Windows Application.

From menus choose Project +  Properties, and navigate to Output type: drop down, change to Windows Application then run your application

Of course you should change it back for building a console application intended to run outside of the IDE.

(tested with Visual Studio 2008 and 2010, expect it should work in latter versions too)

Comment: This is a better way if you are looking to quickly copy the results of your application.

Comment: Why does Console.Writeline not work in a Console application? This sounds very counter intuitive.

Comment: ^^ Yeah, what? This has always worked. And now it's not. This feels like a bug in Visual Studio.

Comment: I have a Class Library. Impossible to change to Windows Application... At least System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine works...

Answer (score 17):

Using `Console.WriteLine( "Test" );` is able to write log messages to the Output Window (View Menu --> Output) in Visual Studio for a Windows Forms/WPF project.

However, I encountered a case where it was not working and only `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine( "Test" );` was working. I restarted Visual Studio and `Console.WriteLine()` started working again. Seems to be a Visual Studio bug.

Comment: And also; building stuff in VS switches the output window to build; so now I have to click output, change item in 'show output from' AND scroll through tens of other messages.

Comment: As of today, in VS 2019 ( Ver. 16.11.19 ) this is the correct answer! Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Try to uncheck the CheckBox “Redirect all Output Window text to the Immediate Window” in

```
Tools => Options => Debugging => General
```

I had it checked and everything was written in the Immediate Window and not in the Output Window

Answer (score 3):

If you are developing a command line application, you can also use `Console.ReadLine()` at the end of your code to wait for the 'Enter' keypress before closing the console window so that you can read your output. However, both the Trace and Debug answers posted above are better options.

Comment: How does that answer the question?

Answer (score 2):

When issue happening on Mac VS 2017 (Which I faced).

1. Go to Project >> "Your Project name" options.
2. An option window will pop up
3. Go to RUN >> Default menu option
4. Tick the "Run on external console" option TRUE and say OK

Run your application code now.

Answer (score 2):

Try to uncheck the CheckBox “Use Managed Compatibility Mode” in

> Tools => Options => Debugging => General

It worked for me.

Comment: I had this on when debugging a previous cpp/cli project and apparently causes this issue as well as NLog not logging to console.

Answer (score -2):

Old Thread, But in VS 2015 Console.WriteLine does not Write to Output Window If "Enable the Visual Studio Hosting Process" does not Checked or its Disabled in Project Properties -> Debug tab