# Visual studio produces error on using `Console.WriteLine()`

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, uwp

Ok, so I am using C# for the first time and am using Visual Studio. I edited the `MainPage.xaml.cs` with my simple code and Visual Studio raised an error that `The name 'Console' does not exist in the current context`. Here is an image of the same:

[image]

The code of the file is given below, but I can't understand what's wrong here...

```cs
// The `using` statements were pre-given in the original (default) code
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

namespace App1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me out...

Comment: Console is for use in console applications. When you created this solution, did you select Console Application?

Comment: Umm, no, @NicholasHunter As mentioned it's the first time I'm using C#, so I'm sorry for any mistakes... It is actually for a Universal Windows App. Please tell me what I should  do...

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44714163/i-cannot-use-debug-print-or-console-writeline-as-i-get-the-error-the-name-co

Comment: You seem to have edited more than just `MainPage.xaml.cs`. Or where is the above `Program` class implemented. Remove it. It makes no sense in a UWP app.

Comment: Has your question been solved? If yes, you could post the solution as an answer and mark yourself, which will help others that faces the same question.