# Create an app for both console usage and windows usage

Tags: c#, console-application, windows

I have an app I would like to create to be used as a console environment as well as a Windows environment.

For example...

### 1) From command window

I want to open command prompt and type `myapp.exe --help` for it to show my the console output of...

```
c:\myapp.exe

Usage: myapp.exe [--option]
Switches:
  --help : Shows this information.
  --ver  : Shows version.
```

### 2) From window

I want to double click on `myapp.exe` and it to show a form window instead.

---

Currently I do this by setting the project type to `Console Application` but this also shows a console window under my form when I double click it.

Is there a way to create the application to be used in both environments?

Comment: [AttachConsole](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681952.aspx)

Comment: Show or Hide Console : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571627/show-hide-the-console-window-of-a-c-sharp-console-application

Comment: I'm not sure if I should flag this as a dup or just delete it.  @IInspectable that lead me to exactly what I needed...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/807998/how-do-i-create-a-c-sharp-app-that-decides-itself-whether-to-show-as-a-console-o